# asp.net MVC 5 how to return max value with the where or single condition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

here I have tried but not result the value:

```
int id = 10;
var HighValue = db.dab.Where(a => a.ItemId== id).Max(a => a.ReqValue);
decimal TempValue = HighValue.ReqValue;
return Content(TempValue);
```

here for sure the **HighValue** is list, but how I am able to only show one value which need to be max

regards

Comment: Are you sure `HighValue` is a list? `Max` returns an `int` so you could just use `decimal TempValue = HighValue;` or `return Content(HighValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
int id = 10;
var HighValue = db.dab.Where(a => a.ItemId== id).OrderByDescending(p => p.ReqValue).First();
decimal TempValue = HighValue.ReqValue;
return Content(TempValue);
```